# The meaning of variables and derivations in Souriau's book

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry

As far as I see, Souriau is using unconventional notions in his book *"Structure of Dynamical Systems"*. He explains these notions in §2. of Chapter I, but it is a puzzle for me. Mainly because he regularly talks about mappings without mentioning the domain or the co-domain of these mappings. Could somebody tell me in the language of the conventional differential geometry what  the exact meaning (and perhaps the benefit) of Souriau's $\delta$ symbol is?

Edit 1:

The relevant pages of the book are shown [here](https://books.google.hu/books?id=4tBrbryIKQAC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=souriau+variables+derivations&source=bl&ots=tWDfuIOuOj&sig=ruN1XP9ebVbfYUWPTtdfD6DgZRE&hl=hu&sa=X&ei=eGzcVNKnI4jvaN-ngOgK&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=souriau%20variables%20derivations&f=false).

Edit 2:

[Here](http://www.jmsouriau.com/structure_des_systemes_dynamiques.htm) it is the complete book (French original).

Comment: It'll be good to provide a link to the text. The most obvious variant is to put link to Google Books, however it didn't worked for me: it doesnt' show pages the pages that I want.